# Approximating function of the integral $\dfrac{\sin(x)^k}{x^k}$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation-theory

I needed a formula giving the value of the following integral;
$$J(k)=\int_0^\pi dx\dfrac{\sin(x)^k}{x^k}$$
I didn't find any analytic expresion for it.
I only found this interpolating function:
$$J(k)=a\left(b^{\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)}\right)k^c-d$$
with: $a = 2.173,b = 0.8536,c = -0.4982,d = -0.002996$.
valid until $k = 200$ with small error. Is t known any best fitting for $J(k)$?
Thanks

Comment: You should try to use the sine integral [$\text{Si}(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Comment: [sinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) might also be useful

Comment: And use [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), the formulas for multiple angles.

Comment: Unfortunately is not easy to found $J(k)$ as a combination of $Si(x)$

Comment: Is $k$ an integer ?

Comment: Below my answer are comments that give you an overview of what was needed for the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the trigonomy formulas for $(\sin x)^n$ and applying partial integration, I've got with $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

> $$J(n)=\int\limits_0^\pi\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n dx = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^k{\binom n k}\left(\frac{n}{2}-k\right)^{n-1}\text{Si}((n-2k)\pi)$$

Comment: Could you expand a little ?

Comment: Not explicitly, that's too much to write. I have used: 
$~\sin^n x = \frac{1}{2^n}{\binom n {n/2}} + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n/2-1}(-1)^{n/2-k}{\binom n k}\cos((n-2k)x)$ for even $n~$ and $~\sin^n x = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}(-1)^{(n-1)/2}{\binom n k}\sin((n-2k)x)$ for odd $n~$ . Then dividing by $x^n$ and partial integration.

Comment: No problem with the linearization of $\sin^k$, rather with the rest.

Comment: And I’ve used: 
$~\int\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^{2n-1}}dx = -\frac{\sin(ax)}{(2n-2)x^{2n-2}} + \frac{a}{2n-2}\int\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2n-2}}dx~$ and 
$~\int\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2n}}dx = -\frac{\cos(ax)}{(2n-1)x^{2n-1}}- \frac{a}{2n-1}\int\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^{2n-1}}dx~$ .

Comment: The rest which has nothing to do with $Si(x)$ becomes $0$ by setting $x=0$ (unpleasant to calculate) and $x=\pi$ (simple to calculate).