# Sum regularization/ use of generalized functions in Ramanujan master theorem applied to inverse function of $\frac{\sin(x)}x$

Tags: generating-functions, inverse-function, dirac-delta, regularization, mellin-transform

$\def\Si{\operatorname{Si}}$

The [converse Ramanujan master theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795225/is-the-converse-of-ramanujans-master-theorem-also-true) finds Taylor series coefficients. The goal of our question is applying it on $h(x)=\cases{f^{-1}(x),x\ge1\\ 0,0\le x<1}$:
[image]

where $f(x)=x\csc(x)$. The Mellin transform of $h(x)$ is:

$$\operatorname M_s(h(t))=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}h(t)dt=\int_1^\infty t^{s-1}h(t)dt=\int_0^\pi t f(t)^{s-1}df(t)$$

Integrating by parts, letting $s=n\in\Bbb N$ using [Approximating function of the integral $\dfrac{\sin(x)^k}{x^k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413798/approximating-function-of-the-integral-dfrac-sinxkxk) gives the [$\Si(x)$ function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Si%28x%29)
$$\operatorname M_n(h(t))=-\frac1n\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^{-n}dx= \frac{1}{(-n-1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{-n-1}2\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}n{\binom {-n} k}\left(\frac{-n}{2}-k\right)^{-n-1}\text{Si}((-n-2k)\pi)=\Gamma(n)a_{-n}$$

so possibly:

$$h(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n(-x)^n}{n!},a_n= \frac{1}{\color{red}{\Gamma(-n)}(n-1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^ {\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor}(-1)^k{\binom n k}\left(\frac{n}{2}-k\right)^{n-1}\text{Si}((n-2k)\pi) \tag 1$$

Unfortunately, $\Gamma(-n)$ complicates convergence. However, as @Tom Copeland mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379428/ramanujans-master-formula-a-proof-and-relation-to-umbral-calculus/379453#comment1132660_379453) $\Gamma(-n)$ in $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty t^{-n-1} f(t)dt\frac{(-x)^n}{n!\Gamma(-n)}$ making the sum terms $0$:

> Roughly you are neglecting that $1/t$ tends to infinity as $t$ tends to $0$. Review the use of delta functions and the Gelfand-Shilov rep. Other more elementary intros to generalized functions and regularization of integrals are useful (Kanwal maybe)

there is a possibility of fixing $(1)$’s convergence and removing the $\Gamma(-n)$ by regularization/use of generalized functions, but how?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-n)}=0$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ making $a_n=0$.

Comment: @Gary This was addressed in the block quoted comment starting with “Roughly, …”. Is there any way to regularize, etc, the sum?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. You are trying to obtain the Taylor series coefficients of $h(x)$ at $0$, but it seems these coefficients should all be zero since $h(x)$ is the zero function there. Since $h(x)$ is a piecewise function, you won't get a Taylor series that captures both parts.  Are you perhaps trying to find a Taylor series for the $h(x)>1$ instead?

Comment: @CalebBriggs Yes, an explicit expansion for $h(x)$ for $x>1$.The piecewise function was for making the function continuous on $[0,\infty)$ so the Ramanujan master theorem was maybe applicable. An equivalent problem is expanding $h(1/x),0\le x\le 1$, inverting $\frac{\sin(x)}x$, about $x=0$ using the same method. What ideas do you have?